# How can a function with formal parameter of type int*& can take both int and int* as arguments while calling it?

Tags: c++, function

```
void swap(int* &x, int* &y)  //reference to pointer to int
{
    int t=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=t;
}
int main()
{
    int x=10, y=20;
    cout<<x<<" "<<y<<endl;
    swap(x,y);               //No compilation error showed even though the
                             //args are of type int instead of int*

    cout<<x<<" "<<y<<endl;
}
```

The swap function takes references to pointers to integers. But I saw that it can even take args of type int and swap them. How is it possible?

```
Output: 10 20
        20 10
```

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;`!

Comment: Omg Thanks. Now its showing an error. Whats the reason behind this?

Comment: [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

Comment: @soubhiksen, as Evg said, when you add "using namespace std;", your code uses the std::swap() method and NOT your local swap() method. So, you don't see any error. But after you remove "using namespace std;", your code uses your local swap() method, which causes the compile error.